# How to enable /disable login page in flutter

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

Please help me Master..
I have an application which there is a secure login feature using a password. Every time the user opens the application, the user is redirected from MainPage to the LoginPage to enter the password.

I want to make a choice for the user to enable or disable secure login on the SettingsPage. If the user activates secure login, every time he opens the application the user redirected from MainPage to LoginPage. And if the user disabled secure login, the user is immediately redirected from MainPage to the HomePage

**Example**

if Secure Login Enable :

*MainPage -> LoginPage -> HomePage*

if Secure Login Disable :

*MainPage -> HomePage*

**MainPage Code**

```
// MainPage
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'MainPage',
      home: LoginPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

**LoginPage Code**

```
// LoginPage
class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

**HomePage Code**

```
// HomePage
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
          child: InkWell(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text(
              'Settings',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => SettingsPage()));
        },
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

**SettingsPage Code**

```
// SettingsPage
class SettingsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SettingsPageState createState() => _SettingsPageState();
}

class _SettingsPageState extends State<SettingsPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Container(
          child: InkWell(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text(
              'Secure Login enabled/disabled',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        onTap: () {},
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: why dont save whether the password page has been enabled or not using sharedpreferences, can on the main page navigate the user to the home page if it's false else navigate the user to the loginpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Shared Preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) and do this.

```
// Button function to enabled/disable
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

//  Check if it was disabled previously
final bool disabled = await prefs.getBool('yourKey');

// Set flag depending if it was enable/disabled
prefs.setBool('yourKey', disabled == null? true : !disabled );
```

and before you navigate to LoginPage you should check if he disabled it.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
final bool disabled = await prefs.getBool('yourKey');
```

Comment: Sir, can you please write it in my code above? I beg you Sir, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The idea to do that is to use [Shared Preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) Package like the following example:

1. Initialize the shared preferences

   `SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();`
2. Store a boolean value according to user's Choice from the setting page according to your need like: CheckBox

   `await prefs.setBool('CUSTOM_KEY_HERE', user's_bool_value_here);`
3. retrieve that value everytime when the user enters MainPage() as following

   ```dart
   bool isSecureMode = prefs.getBool('CUSTOM_KEY_HERE'); // make sure it is the same key
   if (isSecureMode) {
   // go to HomePage
   } else {
   // go to LoginPage
   }
   ```

Comment: thanks for your answer my friend, but I don't know what code to write on each of the pages mentioned above